# store an int in a node

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Fraction { 
    int num;
    int denom;
};

struct PolyTerm {
    int expo;
    struct Fraction coeff;
};

struct PolyNode {
    struct PolyTerm* dataPtr;
    struct PolyNode* next;
};

typedef struct Fraction* FractionAddr;
typedef struct PolyNode* PolyNodeAdr;
typedef struct PolyNode* PolyList;

int main() {
    int exponet;
    PolyNodeAdr polyNode = 0;

    printf("\n\tPlease Enter expoent: ");
    scanf("%d", &exponet);

    polyNode->dataPtr->expo = exponet;

    //printf("\n%d\n",polyNode->dataPtr->expo);

    return;
}
```

on the above code, I am trying to store the exponet into the expo in the struct of polynode

but I tried many ways, but errors keep appearing

isn't expo is an int? why I can't store the exponet (int) into it?

I checked a few ways, when I just put `struct PolyTerm dataPtr;`in the struct of polyNode

and `polyNode->dataPtr.expo = exponet;` in the main, it would work

I think because the dataPtr is a pointer`struct PolyTerm* dataPtr;`

but I have no idea to fix it

can anyone explain to me why I can't do that and what is the solution for it?

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: polynode does not point to anything. you are dereferencing a NULL pointer.  Even DataPtr is NULL.

Comment: i am using visual C++, and I can run the code, but after I inserted the exponet, the window message pop out and said stopped working

Comment: can you put up some more of your code?

Comment: @Koushik - actually, `dataPtr` can be anything, even potato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for all pointers that you gonna dereference. And free the memory after you are done with it.

```
int main() {
    int exponet;
    PolyNodeAdr polyNode = (PolyNodeAdr)malloc(sizeof(PolyNode));
    polyNode->dataPtr = (PolyTerm*)malloc(sizeof(PolyTerm));

    printf("\n\tPlease Enter expoent: ");
    scanf("%d", &exponet);

    polyNode->dataPtr->expo = exponet;

    //printf("\n%d\n",polyNode->dataPtr->expo);

    free(polyNode->dataPtr);
    free(polyNode);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh, actually i have the allocate memory for the node, but not for the dataPtr, that why it was not working, I thought polyNodePtr is the only pointer, I didn't think i need to allocate the pointer inside it. ok thank you!

Comment: Please don't cast the result of `malloc` in C. It's not necessary and some even [argue that it's bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

`polyNode == NULL`

`dataPtr == anything`.

so `polyNode->dataPtr->expo` is actually `(NULL)->dataPtr->expo`. it doesnt have meaning. there is segmentation fault because you are trying to access a restricted memory. thats why windows pops that message.

EDIT:thanks to @Nik for pointing out the errors in my answer.

Comment: First of, `dataPtr` isn't `NULL`: it's *nothing at all*. `polyNode->dataPtr->expo` is actually `(NULL)->dataPtr->expo` - dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is bad. Secondly, `polyNod` isn't a struct - it's a *pointer* to a struct, and initializing a pointer to `0` is perfectly valid and correct.

Comment: @NikBougalis thanks for pointing them out. corrected my answer. hope it dint mislead the OP.

Answer (score 0):

No memory was allocated for `PolyNodeAdr polyNode`

You have to add this after your declaration of polyNode for `polyNode->dataPtr->expo = exponet;` to work

```
polyNode = malloc( sizeof( struct PolyNode )) ;
polyNode->dataPtr = malloc( sizeof( struct PolyTerm )) ;
```

Note the usage of `struct PolyNode` not `PolyNodeAdr` since you changed   `PolyNodeAdr` to a pointer with typedef.

Also you shouldn't typedef a pointer, since you lose the information that the name is a pointer.

For example:

```
typedef struct PolyNode* PolyNodeAdr;
```

Should be:

```
typedef struct PolyNode PolyNodeAdr;
```

So later you declare:

```
PolyNodeAdr * polyNode;
```

Comment: ok ty, but for the typedef the poitner, I think both ways are work?

Comment: Yes of course both ways will work, but one is much more readable.